# How to create a formula in excel to check a range for integers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, integer

As stated I want to create a formula in excel to check a range of cells if any of them are not integers.

I have a range of cells, `B2:J2`, and I want to put a formula in a separate box that will display "`True`" if all the cells are integers, and "`False`" if not.

I have tried using `INT` function but was unable to apply it to the range.
I also created a nested if statement based on this formula:

```
=IF(INT(J2)=J2,TRUE,FALSE)
```

I can't post the entire formula from my phone but the formula got very long.  It seems to work but I was curious to see if there was a better way to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT to iterate the range and count:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(INT(B1:J1)<>B1:J1))=0
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MOD(B2:J2,1))=0
```

The objection here is that it might not work for negative numbers. In fact it does, because the MOD function returns any fraction part as a positive number even if the number is negative.